# New identity on tor vs advor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ip-address

I have a question about the difference between AdvOR (advanced onion router) and tor. When I use tor's new identity option, I only get a portion of the total amount of IPs on the tor network. Once those IPs are banned, I can no longer access a site using tor. However, with AdvOR (advanced onion router) I can use the new identity option and I suddenly have access to a lot more IP addresses than I normally get from the original tor browser. Does tor only give you a fixed number of new identities? Because on AdvOR, I have tor exit nodes which I never get through the standard tor browser.

Answer (score 1):

Tor's path selection uses faster relays more often, which might give the impression that some exit relays are never chosen. It appears that AdvOR doesn't exhibit the same behaviour and thus chooses exits the regular Tor client would pick only very rarely with a higher frequency.